# CLI tool written in rust occurs error when using completion of fish at the first time

Tags: rust, command-line-interface, fish

**Problem describe:**

I have written a CLI tool for wsl to learn rust.
It can open files using explorer.exe of Windows.
I call it 'op'.

The problem is every time I open a new wsl and
type 'op ' in fish shell,
and use 'Tab' to get completions,
then there will raise an error:

```
> op error: the directory does not exist
Oops: command not found
- (line 1):
Oops "./completion"
^~~^
from sourcing file -
        called on line 1 of file /usr/share/fish/completions/op.fish
from sourcing file /usr/share/fish/completions/op.fish
```

(Text 'op' is colored and others are white)

/usr/share/fish/completions/op.fish:

```
op completion fish | source
```

It seems relates to fish shell (3.6.0) (bash no bug because there is no completions). But this bug only occurs one time, command 'op' will make sense as expect after that.

I have a 'minigrep' which following [the book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch12-00-an-io-project.html). It run perfectly with no bug.

**Source code (main.rs):**

```rust
// This is a minimal frame
// The complete code is in https://github.com/GlekoMa/op
use std::env;
use std::path::Path;
use std::process::Command;

fn main() {
    // 0. get env args
    let args: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();

    // 1. convert args[1] to Path
    let path = Path::new(&args[1]);

    // 2. parse path to parent and file_name
    let parent = path.parent().unwrap();
    let file_name = path.file_name().unwrap().to_str().unwrap();

    // 3. cd parent path
    env::set_current_dir(parent).unwrap();

    // 4. execute open (using exeplorer.exe) cmd
    let cmd_open = format!("explorer.exe {file_name}");
    Command::new("sh").arg("-c").arg(cmd_open).output().unwrap();
}
```

**Behavior expected:**

Type 'op ' and use 'Tab' for completion will raise no error.

---

**Update & Solution**

Thanks to @faho, the source of this bug (is not related to the rust source code) is described below:

Somehow there is a completion fish script op.fish (generally is generated by software with same name.) in /usr/share/fish/completions.
But my 'op' does not generate it, so this op.fish clashed with my 'op' for completion.

There are two simple ways to fix it:

1. Rename 'op' (not by alias but by rebuilding).
2. Write an empty file to ~/.config/fish/completions/op.fish so that fish will load it instead of /usr/share/fish/completions/op.fish.

I have used 2nd way and 'op' works well now!

Comment: Please include a [mre] of the code that reproduces this error **within** the question, a mere link to an external resource does not suffice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code has a debug print:

https://github.com/GlekoMa/op/blob/7ae843acbd37a3f64b162aaf4b984094c7be0aa8/src/main.rs#L17

> ```
> println!("Oops {:?}", path); // This code is for debug.
> ```

This prints `Oops ...`, and so fish will, because you told it to `source` the output, attempt to run it as a command, and the command "Oops" won't exist and so it will print an error.

This will only happen when the completions are loaded, which fish typically does the first time you try to complete something.

Remove that debug statement, don't print it when generating the completions (i.e. you get the `completion` subcommand), print it to stderr instead (which means it will show up when the completions are loaded!) or prefix it with a `//` to make it a comment.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
The code `println!("Oops {:?}", path);` is added after I found this bug at begin. If comment it, there still a bug:

Comment: `> op error: the directory does not exist`

(I add `println!` to debug and then found it relates to fish completions.)

Comment: Thanks again for explaining the fish completion load behavior. I have found the source of the bug. It's completely my fault. Sorry about that!

Answer (score 0):

I have found the source of the bug while create a minimal reproducible example:

I created a new project with identical code and found it ran perfectly without this bug!

So I deleted file /usr/share/fish/completions/op.fish and try running 'op' in a new terminal. No error raised this time.

Apologize for my foolishness!

Comment: You don't want to mess with files in /usr/share. Those will just be overwritten when you update fish. Think of it as your package managers domain. Instead, to disable the "op" completions, write an empty file to ~/.config/fish/completions/op.fish.

Comment: Also, the reason fish has this file is because there is a tool called `op` and that is how you complete it. Your tool has a name clash with it, and you might want to think about renaming it.

Comment: At begin I thought fish will generate a new completion script if it detected a new software.
 
The reason why I thought so is I have a software named 'zola' installed from internet, and I saw there is a 'zola.fish' in /usr/share/fish/completions.

Had seen your comments, I backed to there and found the library 'clap' (a command line argument parser) used by 'zola' can auto generate a fish completion script..

Comment: Confused that I don't have a tool named 'op' before (checked by `whereis op`). But at least I have known what should do now.

I recovered /usr/share/fish/completions/op.fish and added an empty file to ~/.config/fish/completions/op.fish. It works perfect.

Thanks for your detailed explanation!